# A better way to compare a variable number of lists to each other for equality

Tags: python, list, comparison, equality

I am in a bit of a conundrum here, I am looking for an easy and dynamic way to check if all lists in a dictionary of lists are the same.

Below is an example of what I am doing now, but obviously my lists contain real data (strings):

```
def sample_method(var=10):
    d = {}
    for i in range(var):
        d[i] = range(10)
    return d

def compare_method(d):
    lists = d.values()
    first = lists[0]
    for lst in lists[1:]:
        if first != lst:
            return False
    return True  

print compare_method(sample_method(5))
# returns True
```

I want a much simpler way to compare if all the lists are the same. My preference is that it would be a one-liner, something like:

```
def desired_method():
    # logic to get d.
    if "all lists are equal": # replace this with the one-liner logic.
        # do more logic.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
if len(set(tuple(i) for i in d.values())) == 1
```

This first converts the lists into tuples so that they can be put into a set (lists aren't hashable). The set removes all duplicates, so if the length of the set is `1`, all elements in the list must be the same.